# Control Theory - Designing Proportional Controller for Quadcopter Equation of Motions

Tags: systems-of-equations, mathematical-modeling, control-theory

I was trying to design proportional controller for quadcopter equation of motions roll, pitch and yaw angles.

I tried to build up some equations but when i try to stabilize the step response of my equations, it is impossible to stabilize with proportional controller.

Is there a way to do that or do i have to use pid controller to stabilize the system?

Here is my MATLAB code for stabilizing roll angle with moment of inertia is 0.0089:

```
H_roll=tf([0 0 1],[0.0089 0 0]);
K=25;
H=(K*H_roll)/(1+(K*H_roll))
step(H)
K=50;
Kd=25;
C=pid(K,0,Kd);
T=feedback(C*H_roll,1);
step(T)
stepinfo(T)
Ki=30;
Cpid=pid(K,Ki,Kd);
Tpid=feedback(Cpid*H_roll,1);
step(Tpid)
stepinfo(Tpid)
```

Thanks for any answers from now.
Regards...

Comment: You should write down the equations of motion and maybe give a picture of control loop structure. It is very uncomfortable to reconstruct this from your Matlab code.

Comment: You can easily analyze proportional control by root-locus or Nyquist plots. Both have dedicated functions in Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

Your transfer function for `H_roll` is just double integrator with a gain, which can be seen as exerting a force on a mass on top of a frictionless surface. Now by adding only a proportional controller you effectively add an ideal spring. So once the system with "spring" starts oscillating it will always keep oscillating.

However if you instead would use a PD controller, you would basically add a spring and a damper to the system. This system will eventually come to rest, since the "damper" will dissipate away the kinetic energy from the system.

Comment: Thanks your answer @KwinvanderVeen how can i change the system to stabilize only by using proportional controller? I mean what can i add to this system maybe  a filter or something else.

Comment: @MrvGMSTKN As stated in my answer, you could use a PD controller instead of just a P controller. So a term proportional to the error plus a term proportional to the derivative of the error.